# WebInspect on Production Systems

Tags: security, testing

I have a client who has been using WebInspect on live production systems with live data.  They give the tool a real life user id with real life data, and let WebInspect have at it with full bore form filling.  In at least one case they have damaged production data as a result.  My client is adamant that they have to do this to insure that their website is secure.  To me this seems like an ill-conceived idea.  What are other people's opinions of this?  I've always thought of WebInspect as a developer's tool not a penetration testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

This type of testing is required by the PCI-DSS.   Merchants are required to scan their live site and produce one passing test once every quarter.   Services like [Mcafee Secure](http://www.mcafeesecure.com/us/) and [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/Advisories/List) have the option to scan your site every day.   A very effective approach would be to test a development build of the code base prior to release of any changes.

If there is a problematic form that pollutes your database ,  then you should protect this form with a capthca.  After all isn't that a vulnerability?   Couldn't an attacker intentionally pollute you database?  Really this is a round about way of detecting a vulnerability.

Comment: They give WebInspect a real user ID and password for an online account, and then let WebInspect go whole hog on form filling on that already authenticated account.  We wouldn't want to have every step require a capthca since the user has already logged in.  It's as though they've given WebInspect some random user's real life bank account and then are surprised when WebInspect has done some random thing like transfer funds from the savings account to the credit card account.  Again, they are using REAL LIVE USER accounts and not test accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Rook is correct, WebInspect should not be used in a Production environment without careful consideration of the fall-out.  In my experience, it has been the Crawler that can cause the most havoc and not the Audits/Attacks as everyone assumes.  This is because the Crawler is supposed to exercise all parts of the application presented, without regard, in order to expose the most attack surface area.  If there is a way to transfer funds or a big red button that says please oh please do not press this button, WebInspect is going to do that.

The best method is as Rook describes, scanning in a test environment first.  Once you get all the kinks worked out in your scanning of the test instance, then you can use that scan configuration on your Production site later.  You should use a normal user-level account to authenticate WebInspect, but you should be using a test account and not a real person's account.  Equivalent but not the exact same.

WebInspect offers a bunch of ways to "shape" your scan.  The `Restrict To Folder` option can keep it inside one directory, or that directory and its children.  `Session Exclusions` can prevent WebInspect from visiting specific folders or URLs or forms.  Request Filters can be used to prevent a particular form value from being used, while permitting all others.  `List-Driven` or `Workflow-Driven` scans coupled with the `Audit-Only` method can keep the attacks limited to one area and prevent crawling/discovery of the rest of the site.

If you have further questions, always contact Customer Support, and maybe ask for their Scanning Cookbook or an individual review.

Full disclosure - I have worked supporting and selling WebInspect since 2004.

Answer (score 0):

Webinspect should never be used in production environment as there is every chance that the server could go down, data could be corrupted etc. Penetration testing is usually done in staging or pre prod environment. Check out the below tutorial which explains in details about what you have to do for scanning web applications.

http://webappsecure.blogspot.in/2012/07/hp-webinspect-tutorial.html